# Strange change in total energy when lattice relaxing of EuTiO3 material and then atomic relaxing in a specific direction using Quantum Espresso

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, cell-optimization, spin-polarization

These days, I'm having a trouble in atomic relaxing of "EuTiO3" with tetragonal symmetry using Quantum espresso 7.1 for a period of more that a week. This material have a transverse optical mode to z-axis("001" direction). So, I try to relax this material along the z-axis. My order of relaxing the EuTiO3 is as follows:

1. I download "cif.file" including the atomic position & lattice from "Materials Explorer( https://next-gen.materialsproject.org/materials ) "
2. At Quantum espresso, "vc-relax(lattice realxation)" this material.
3. "Relax" this material along the z-axis(= the direction of transverse optical mode,001).

At "2" process, total energy is decreased. ***But at "3" process, total energy is oddly increased!!***. By other paper related EuTiO3, because this material is unstable to the direction of "z-axis", total energy should be also decreased at "3" process.  I don't know what the reason is.

At similar structure "SrTiO3" with tetragonal symmetry , this problem didn't occur. At "SrTiO3",  the same procedure as above was performed, but total energy was decreased at both "2" & "3" process.

Both "EuTiO3" & "SrTiO3" are perovskite material. One difference is that "EuTiO3" have antiferromagnetic property(=spin polarization) unlike "SrTiO3". Hence, I specified the "magnetization" and "Hubbard potential" to the input data of "EuTiO3"( In another paper, I know that magnetization and Hubbard potential are specified when relaxing EuTiO3 material.)
***Did I typed the "magnetization" & "Hubbard potential" data wrong?*** Please help me. I need sincere help from experts.

P.S  I add my input data of "EuTiO3" entered into Quatum Espresso.

2. process : "vc-relax"

&control
calculation = 'vc-relax'
restart_mode='from_scratch',
prefix='ETO',
pseudo_dir ='/home/dydtlr5506/pseudo',
outdir='./wavefunc'
tstress = .true.
forc_conv_thr = 1.0d-7
dt = 20
disk_io = 'none'
nstep =9910
/
&system
ibrav=  0,
nat=20, ntyp= 4,
ecutwfc = 80.0, ecutrho = 640.0,
occupations = 'smearing',
smearing = 'gaussian'
degauss = 0.0010
nspin = 2
starting_magnetization(1)=7.0
starting_magnetization(2)=-7.0

/ &electrons
mixing_mode = 'plain'
electron_maxstep = 100
conv_thr = 1.0d-13
/
&ions
ion_dynamics = 'bfgs'
/  &cell
cell_dofree='xyz'
cell_dynamics = 'bfgs'
/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Eu1  151.964 Eu.pbe-spdfn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
Eu2  151.964 Eu.pbe-spdfn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
Ti  47.86  Ti.pbe-spn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
O   15.999 O.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
K_POINTS {automatic}
6 6 4 0 0 0
CELL_PARAMETERS (angstrom)
5.510044859   0.000000000   0.000000000
0.000000000   5.510044859   0.000000000
0.000000000   0.000000000   7.871680636
ATOMIC_POSITIONS (crystal)
Eu1           0.0000000000        0.5000000000        0.2500000000    1   1   0
Eu2           0.5000000000        0.0000000000        0.2500000000    1   1   0
Eu1           0.5000000000        0.0000000000        0.7500000000    1   1   0
Eu2           0.0000000000        0.5000000000        0.7500000000    1   1   0
Ti            0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.5000000000    1   1   0
Ti            0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.5000000000    1   1   0
Ti            0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000    1   1   0
Ti            0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.0000000000    1   1   0
O             0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.2500000000    1   1   0
O             0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.2500000000    1   1   0
O             0.7183286073        0.2183286073        0.0000000000    1   1   0
O             0.7816713921        0.2816713922        0.5000000000    1   1   0
O             0.2816713922        0.2183286079        0.5000000000    1   1   0
O             0.2183286073        0.2816713927        0.0000000000    1   1   0
O             0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.7500000000    1   1   0
O             0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.7500000000    1   1   0
O             0.2183286079        0.7183286078        0.5000000000    1   1   0
O             0.2816713927        0.7816713927        0.0000000000    1   1   0
O             0.7816713927        0.7183286073        0.0000000000    1   1   0
O             0.7183286078        0.7816713921        0.5000000000    1   1   0
HUBBARD (ortho-atomic)
U Eu1-4f 5.9
U Eu2-4f 5.9
[image]
2. process: output total energy =   -5712.21091180 Ry

3. process : "relax"

&control
calculation = 'relax'
restart_mode='from_scratch',
prefix='ETO',
pseudo_dir ='/home/dydtlr5506/pseudo',
outdir='./wavefunc'
tstress = .true.
forc_conv_thr = 1.0d-7
dt = 20
disk_io = 'none'
nstep =9910
/
&system
ibrav=  0,
nat=20, ntyp= 4,
ecutwfc = 80.0, ecutrho = 640.0,
!   nbnd =200
!   occupations = 'fixed',
occupations = 'smearing',
smearing = 'gaussian'
degauss = 0.0010
nspin = 2
starting_magnetization(1)=0.5
starting_magnetization(2)=-0.5

!   nosym = .true.
!   nbnd = 120
!   nosym_evc = .true.
!   noinv = .true.
!   no_t_rev = .true.
/
&electrons
mixing_mode = 'plain'
electron_maxstep = 100
conv_thr = 1.0d-9
/
&ions
ion_dynamics = 'bfgs'
/
&cell
cell_dofree='xyz'
cell_dynamics = 'bfgs'

/
ATOMIC_SPECIES
Eu1  151.964 Eu.pbe-spdfn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
Eu2  151.964 Eu.pbe-spdfn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
Ti  47.86  Ti.pbe-spn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
O   15.999 O.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF

K_POINTS {automatic}
6 6 4 0 0 0

CELL_PARAMETERS (angstrom)
5.505334716  -0.000000000   0.000000000
0.000000000   5.505334716   0.000000000
-0.000000000  -0.000000000   7.873593914

ATOMIC_POSITIONS (crystal)
Eu1           0.0000000000        0.5000000000        0.2520000000    0   0   1
Eu2           0.5000000000        0.0000000000        0.2520000000    0   0   1
Eu1           0.5000000000       -0.0000000000        0.7520000000    0   0   1
Eu2          -0.0000000000        0.5000000000        0.7520000000    0   0   1
Ti            0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0040000000    0   0   1
Ti            0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.0040000000    0   0   1
Ti            0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.5040000000    0   0   1
Ti            0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.5040000000    0   0   1
O             0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.2470000000    0   0   1
O             0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.2470000000    0   0   1
O            -0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.7470000000    0   0   1
O             0.5000000000        0.5000000000        0.7470000000    0   0   1
O             0.2179836940        0.2820163063       -0.0020000000    0   0   1
O             0.2820163063        0.7820163060       -0.0020000000    0   0   1
O             0.7179836937        0.2179836940       -0.0020000000    0   0   1
O             0.7820163060        0.7179836937       -0.0020000000    0   0   1
O             0.2179836608        0.7179836609        0.4970000000    0   0   1
O             0.2820163391        0.2179836608        0.4970000000    0   0   1
O             0.7179836609        0.7820163392        0.4970000000    0   0   1
O             0.7820163392        0.2820163391        0.4970000000    0   0   1

HUBBARD (ortho-atomic)
U Eu1-4f 5.9
U Eu2-4f 5.9

[image]

3. process: output total energy =   -5711.56708785 Ry